# use namspace within a <script runat="server"> block

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I want to use Dictinoary class within a `<script runat="server"> block(aspx.cs)`.Whenever I tried to use that class, it showing `The type or namespace name 'Dictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Exception.

How to use `Using System.Collections.Generic`  within a `<script runat="server">` block.I don't want to use this namespace in `.cs` file.

Comment: Yes I tried to use as System.Collections.Generic.Dictinoary<>. But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks for your answers.

Finally I found solution.
The solution  is
 you have to insert the required namespace in the web.config file. Then only you can access the namespace within inline server tag, not by using "using" statement. I have added like this:

```
</assemblies>       
    </compilation>
      <pages>
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
          <add namespace="System.Data"/>
          <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
          <add namespace="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
          <add namespace="System.Resources"/>
          <add namespace="System.Globalization"/>
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified name:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object> objName=new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object>();
```

Now, change the parameters, as you wish.

If it still gives you a error, then, there is something else which is throwing that error and not this.

Comment: Yes I tried to use as System.Collections.Generic.Dictinoary<>. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Sry here I have typed wrongly. But in code it is correct